# Parsing JSON Data working only for template(HTML) but not for Component Class(Typescript)

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I would like to parse a *json* file to use, and extract data.

I don't know why the data extracted from my code work only for my html, but is empty for my typescript code...

json file to parse :

```
[
  {
    "appleWatch": "generation_3",
    "bracelets": ["model_1","model_2","model_3"]
  },
  {
    "appleWatch": "generation_4",
    "bracelets": ["model_1","model_4","model_5"]
  }
]
```

Typescript of my component:

```
export class AppleKitComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) {}

  arrAppleWatch: AppleWatchModel[] = [];
  selectedWatch: AppleWatchModel = null;
  url = '../../assets/json/appleKit.json';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.arrAppleWatch = this.parseAppleWatchData();
    console.log(this.arrAppleWatch.toString() + 'test');
  }

  parseAppleWatchData() {
    this.httpService.get('../../assets/json/appleKit.json').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.arrAppleWatch = data as AppleWatchModel[]; // FILL THE ARRAY WITH DATA.
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    );
    return this.arrAppleWatch;
  }
}
```

My appleWatch model :

```
export class AppleWatchModel {
  constructor(
    public watch: string,
    public bracelets?: string[],
    public bracelet?: string
  ) {
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
{{arrAppleWatch |json }}
```

**My log should output :**

`[ { "appleWatch": "generation_3", "bracelets": [ "model_1", "model_2", "model_3" ] }, { "appleWatch": "generation_4", "bracelets": [ "model_1", "model_4", "model_5" ] } ]`

but it just prints an empty string.

My html work and show the array :

```
[ { "appleWatch": "generation_3", "bracelets": [ "model_1", "model_2", "model_3" ] }, { "appleWatch": "generation_4", "bracelets": [ "model_1", "model_4", "model_5" ] } ]
```

Comment: It's because `ngOnInit` has already been called when your data arrives, because the call is asynchronous, try to move the `log` to the `httpService` callback to confirm (right after the `this.arrAppleWatch = data as AppleWatchModel [];` line)

Comment: Why don't you type the http request? this.httpService.get<AppleWatchModel[]>('../../assets/json/appleKit.json'). Did you try https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your implementation.

The `httpService.get` call call would be an `async` call. So it won't give you the data instantly. But you're trying to access it instantly. Hence you're not getting it in the Component Class.

Give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface AppleWatchModel {
  watch: string;
  bracelets?: string[];
  bracelet?: string;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) {
  }

  arrAppleWatch: AppleWatchModel[] = [];
  selectedWatch: AppleWatchModel = null;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.parseAppleWatchData()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.arrAppleWatch = res;
        console.log('test: ', this.arrAppleWatch);
      });
  }

  parseAppleWatchData() {
    return this.httpService.get<AppleWatchModel[]>('/assets/appleKit.json');
  }
}
```

Here, we're returning an `Observable<AppleWatchModel[]>` from `parseAppleWatchData`. So we can `subscribe` to it in the `ngOnInit` to get the actual data.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/apple-watch-model-eg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Check [Async Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) to avoid manual subscription.

Comment: @youri, I'm aware of it. It's just that OP would definitely need the select watch at some point in time. Hence the manual subscription. Also, it's not like it's a never-ending Observable. So there's essentially no problem of a memory leak. So doesn't really matter for this case.

Answer (score 2):

Your output is empty because you don't take the asynchronous nature of http requests into account. parseAppleWatchData is returned with the original arrAppleWatch value (which is []) before the http response is received. If you add some logs you will see B comes before A. You can also remove the return value.

```
export class AppleKitComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) {
  }

  arrAppleWatch: AppleWatchModel [] = [];
  selectedWatch: AppleWatchModel = null;
  url = '../../assets/json/appleKit.json';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.parseAppleWatchData();
    log('B', this.arrAppleWatch);
  }

 parseAppleWatchData() {
    this.httpService.get('../../assets/json/appleKit.json').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.arrAppleWatch = data as AppleWatchModel [];     // FILL THE ARRAY WITH DATA.
        console.log('A', data);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    );
  }
```